# Highlighted search terms in links makes them to lose underscored style on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, design, highlighting

When searching on any of the SO family sites, search terms are highlighted in the results with a background color. However, this tends to change result links' style to have no 'underlined' style on hover.

Was that intentional?

Example image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intentional by way of CSS working its styles in hierarchy.

Highlighted word in this case has a  CSS style applied to it that comes ahead of the style that is applied to the line as a whole.

So in effect it kind of ignores what's going on in the background because the style that's applied to it takes the cake and the higher order of presentation value.

Comment: But still, I think that highlighting shoudn't break link-specific `underlined` style.

Comment: Moreover, like described in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/make-links-in-monospaced-format-look-more-like-links), the underlining *does* appear in Opera (and perhaps also in IE >7, but I can't test this at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

This no longer happens, never too late for a bugfix eh?