# Make links in monospaced format look more like links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, markdown

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427200/most-efficient-way-to-grow-an-array-in-java/1427244#1427244) I posted a few links that I formatted using backtics.  Because of the new background color and the way the links are formatted it isn't clear right away that they are clickable. (It just looks like they are being syntax highlighted the same way code blocks are.)

As pointed out by rcartaino, hovering over the link does not show an underline like regular links.  The only visual clue a user is given that it's a link is the cursor.

I would recommend that links formatted as code should be underlined.

(These results come from Firefox 3.5, and Chrome 3.  Underline works in Opera and IE 7)

Comment: In addition to *not* looking like links, the link underlining *doesn't* appear when you mouse-over, like it does with regular text links.

Comment: Yup, the hover style doesn't help at all either.  The only visual indicator is the cursor.

Comment: I'd consider this as a [bug], because the results look different in Opera and IE 7/8/9/10 than in FF and Chrome (WebKit?) browsers.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible

Answer (score 6):

In Opera they look like this:

> [image: coded links]

The hover style with the underline is there, along with the colour. But the link looks like a syntax-highlighted keyword, which is missing out on the visual distinction of it being a link.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using FF 3.5, and it doesn't underline the links.

Comment: +1 for freehand free hands.

Comment: I prefer blue hands of god, but nice fingernails :)