# Highlight links in code sections in meta

Tags: discussion, design, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Make links in monospaced format look more like links.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/make-links-in-monospaced-format-look-more-like-links)

If you go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25837/retag-request-source-control it's impossible to know that those tags are, in fact, also links.

[image]

What change do you propose so that links in code blocks really look like links?

Comment: Why do you say it's impossible to tell? I can only tell links by the dotted underline, which those links do have.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/make-links-in-code-more-prominent

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24284

Comment: @mmyers: look at the screenshot. It seems the underline showing depends on the Font/OS/Browser (Firefox 3.5 on Windows 2000).

Comment: It's the same in **Opera** (though you could do with some freehand circles to mark it out) where the CSS for `code` overtakes links.

Comment: Ultimately, tags aren't code. Perhaps don't put them in code markup?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I used to use `<kbd>`, but Jeff thought we were missusing it. Am I wrong?

Comment: The link is broken now (the question was deleted).