# No change in appearance when hovering over link containing backticked code

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, usability, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make links in monospaced format look more like links.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/make-links-in-monospaced-format-look-more-like-links)

Something I spotted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594414/css-not-working-with-php-script/1594503#1594503) today: If a link's text contains backticked code, there is no visual change when hovering over it.

Here is [`an example`](http://www.example.com) of what I mean.  **Edit**: Okay, that's a bad example, because on meta it *does* change when hovered... but see the link above, on main SO there is no visual change when hovering over a backticked link.  On meta, though, there is no indication that it is a link *until* you hover over it, which is also not ideal.

It should either still show the underline (like a normal link), or change the color of the text and/or background slightly, since this is how all other links in text on the site behave.

<sup>I'm not sure whether this is a bug or a feature request, but I'm tagging it as bug since I think it was probably an oversight (i.e. it probably wasn't designed this way on purpose).</sup>