# Why are some of my question titles blue and others gray?

Tags: support, design

When I look at [the question page of my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062933/easi?tab=questions), I see some question titles in blue, and others in more of a gray, but I don't understand why.

Here's a picture of what I see, in case you don't see the same color differences when you visit my page yourself. The second, fifth, sixth, and seventh questions are blue, whereas the others are dark gray.

[image: profile question page, with some titles blue and others dark gray]

Comment: i think all of them all in blue because they are your questions. if you download a new css and refresh the browser (Ctrl+F5) they will all be light blue. once you click on some they will be darker blue. its how the CSS for SO is designed

Comment: @mehow they're all my questions because I am on my profile page.

Comment: Why such hurry to destroy my question? Ok, I am not here anymore :-P

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how browsers work and not Stack Exchange.

Comment: @EASI nobody is here to destroy your question, the downvotes are because people are thinking it's too trivial as it's pure HTML issue.

Comment: @EASI no one is destroying your question, but it is extremely unclear what you are asking.  Even if it gets closed, you can still edit it, and if you edit the question to make it more clear what you are asking, it can get reopened.

Comment: it's about SO CSS schema, so it's about stackoverflow. If I knew that it was just because the link was not clicked yet, I wasn't going to ask that question. Can it get any clear than that? :-/ What happens is that some people get too rush...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards it's not about how browsers work really. So many sites use the exact same colour for visited and not that people don't even realize browsers know which links you've visited and which you haven't. It's really a choice about the UI styles the sites have chosen and that they haven't chosen to suppress this distinction by using the same colour for both.

Comment: Hyperlinks then @Kate; I don't really see why it's about Stack Exchange at all, but I'll bow happily to the community's decision.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The blue color simply means you still did not visit that link in that specific browser.

Anchor color is #0077cc ([image]) while visited anchor color is #4a6b82 ([image]).

There is a related post here: [Visited links should be more visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52942/152859)

Comment: They're both different shades of blue, so one can even say that all titles are always blue, because that's simply the color that was chosen.

Comment: @Servy the first one is "more blue" in my opinion... :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd to blue, or not to blue. That is the question.