# I can't see links, it looks like text, do I need glasses?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

There are two links in here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20737676/340760

In the image it is more visible probably because of some quality changes:

[image: links]

Is it just me? If it is not just me, could this be considered a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: Hyperlinks become rather hard to spot once you've visited the link, because of the color they use. See [Visited links should be more visible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible).