# (almost) Invisible links in comments

Tags: bug, comments, design, hyperlinks

I just [commented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49510/only-reverse-in-english-characters-in-arabic-language-using-c#comment87083_49510) on an off-topic post on 
[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) with 3 different links. Two of them were magic links. I referred a User to [so], mentioning (and linking) the guidelines (on-topic help). And when I looked at the links, they were almost indistinguishable from the normal text:

> [image: Invisible comment links]

And here the same, with all three links marked:

> [image: Marked comment links]

For reference, `:visited` links have this hex-code: #18529a
And normal links have: #4e82c2

Comment: I'd like to add, that the duplicated post is more than 2 years old, and the described Hex-Codes are different;)